Converting Excel VBA to Google Apps Script
Would anyone be able to help convert this VBA script to Google Apps Script?
Function SplitSheet() {

Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleSheetsBasedOnColumn()

    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim nLastRow, nRow, nNextRow As Integer

    Dim strColumnValue As String

    Dim objDictionary As Object

    Dim varColumnValues As Variant

    Dim varColumnValue As Variant

    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet

   

    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   

    For nRow = 2 To nLastRow

        strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value

        If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then

           objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1

        End If

    Next

   

    varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys

   

    For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)

        varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)

        Set objSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

        objSheet.Name = varColumnValue

        objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy objSheet.Rows(1)

        For nRow = 2 To nLastRow

            If CStr(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then

                objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy

                nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

            End If

        Next

        objSheet.Columns("A:F").AutoFit

    Next

End Sub

}

I have tried reading other community boards to try and do manual conversions but I keep getting stuck on certain functions.

this VBA script Thanks for including the script. Others might be able to convert this based purely on the VBA, but most users would find it helpful if you were to also provide a description of what the script is doing, and include some sample data as well as an example of the expected outcome.

I'm guessing that you don't have a Google Workspace Enterprise Plus account or a Google Workspace for Education Plus account. If you do, then there is a Google Macro Converter add-on available

Here's how to take the values in column A2:A and create a new tab per each unique name in that column, in each new tab copying rows where that tab's name is in A2:A:
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
'use strict';

/**
* Adds a tab per each unique value in column A2:A of the active sheet, and 
* copies data from rows in the active sheet to those tabs per values in A2:A.
*/
function splitSheetData() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 2 September 2024
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78939631/13045193
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const _showMessage = (msg) => { ss.toast(msg, '', 30); console.log(msg) };
  _showMessage(`Splitting data to new tabs...`);
  const dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetNames = dataSheet.getRange('A2:A').getDisplayValues().flat();
  const data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  const numberFormats = dataSheet.getDataRange().getNumberFormats().slice(1)
    .map(row => row.map(v => v || null)); // handle cells whose number format has not been set
  let numNewSheets = 0;
  const errorTabs = [];
  sheetNames.filter(String).filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).forEach(sheetName => {
    const newSheet = dataSheet.copyTo(ss);
    try {
      newSheet.setName(sheetName);
    } catch (_) {
      ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);
      errorTabs.push(sheetName);
      return;
    }
    const [newData, newNumberFormats] = [data, numberFormats].map(d => d.filter((row, i) => sheetNames[i] === sheetName));
    try {
      newSheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0).clearContent()
        .offset(0, 0, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData).setNumberFormats(newNumberFormats);
    } catch (_) {
      ; // // handle cells whose number format has not been set
    }
    numNewSheets += 1;
  });
  _showMessage(`Created ${numNewSheets} tabs. ${errorTabs.length ? `Did not modify ${errorTabs.length} existing tabs: ${errorTabs.join()}.` : ''}`);
}

The function uses the active sheet as a template and makes copies of it, retaining the header row and cell formatting. Values and number formats are copied over by filtering rows in the template tab by sheet name.
To run the code easily, add a button, a custom menu item, a sidebar or a trigger.
See Apps Script at Stack Overflow and Clean Code JavaScript.
